# Not able to install Vue CLI in Linux terminal

Tags: node.js, linux, vue.js, npm

I am trying to install the Vue CLI globally, but I'm getting the following error after running the command `sudo npm i -g @vue/cli`

Error:

```
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/<system_user_name>/.npm/_cacache/tmp/aa05074f
npm ERR! errno EROFS
npm ERR! rofs Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@vue%2fcli-service: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/home/ravinder/.npm/_cacache/tmp/aa05074f'
npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems
npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.
```

I have also checked `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, here @vue folder is available already.

Please help me with the above issue. Moreover, I feel sorry for typo mistakes.
Thanks in advance

Comment: does this helps you ? https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/26#issuecomment-206991754

Comment: @KareemDabbeet, I have visited to the url but getting the error regarding symlinks when try the command npm config set unsafe-perm true

Comment: just try to escape this command and move to the second one

Comment: I have tried but getting the error

npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, rmdir '/root/.npm/_cacache'
npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems
npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.

Comment: are you trying to install it on a server or shared host ?

Comment: On my Local Machine, It has Linux OS.

Comment: @RavinderSingh Can you give a little more info about your system?